# Ruby on Rails conditional routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have a site listing many jobs, but I also want each account to be able to access its jobs in one place. Thus, I am using these routes:

```
map.resources :jobs
map.resource :account, :has_many => :jobs
```

This gets me URLs like `localhost/jobs/` and `localhost/account/jobs`. However, both seem to render `JobsController::index`. How can I either make a conditional in the index action (how do I access whether account/jobs or just jobs was specified in the URL?) or change the account route to render a different action? What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: Do you have one or multiple accounts? The statement "I also want each account..." suggests multiple, but "map.resource :account" suggests one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a block when creating your routes, and then pass a `:controller` parameter, like so

```
map.resource :account do |account|
  # If you have a special controller 'AccountJobsController'
  account.resources :jobs, :controller => "account_jobs"
end
```

It may be cleaner for you to put your controllers into a directory structure, and then you can reference them in a nested way. For example:

```
map.resource :account do |account|
  account.resources :jobs, :controller => "accounts/jobs"
end
```

If you use the above snippet, you should then create a controller in app/controllers/accounts/jobs_controller.rb, which is defined like so:

```
class Account::JobsController < ApplicationController
  ##
  ## etc.
  ##
end
```

You can always use `rake routes` to check which routes have been generated and which controllers they'll use.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a requirement to the resource definition allows you to pass extra parameters

```
map.resources :jobs
map.resource :account, :has_many => :jobs, :requirements => {:account => true}
```

Then `params[:account]` will be set if the routing url was 'http://www.mysite.tld/account/jobs' and unset if it it was 'http://www.mysite.tld/jobs'

As with all other restful routing the action depends on the context.

- GET requests without an id route to index.
- GET requests with an id route to show
- POST requests route to create
- PUT requests route to update
- DELETE requests route to destroy.

Answer (score 0):

If you run "rake routes" you should see something like this

```
account_jobs  GET    /accounts/:account_id/jobs/:job_id    {:controller => 'jobs', :action => 'index'}
```

This means when your action is called via the /account/jobs route you should have an :account_id parameter. You can then do your logic switch based on the existence of this param:

```
if params[:account_id].nil?
   ...
else
   ...
end
```

Comment: I just did this on a clean rails project to validate, and yes, it does work this way.

routes.rb:
    ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
      map.resources :jobs
      map.resources :accounts, :has_many => :jobs

"rake routes"
    account_jobs GET    /accounts/:account_id/jobs(.:format)          {:controller=>"jobs", :action=>"index"}

get http://localhost:3000/accounts/123/jobs
from log:
    Processing JobsController#index (for 127.0.0.1 at 2009-11-18 11:24:22) [GET]
    Parameters: {"account_id"=>"123"}

Comment: Yikes, sorry for the (non) formatting. My point being... what is the meaning of "this way" in your comment?

Comment: The question specifies account as a resource with map.resource. Meaning there is only one of them. The route you mention is not created for resource that has many resources. But it would have been if account was defined with map.resources.

Comment: Ah! You're absolutely right; I totally missed that it was the singular form of resource in the question. The "each account" bit threw me off.